# Send 404 header after page load

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send a 404 header after the page loads and was wondering if there were any solutions. Essentially, a database is searched to see if the url is valid and corresponds to valid content. If it doesn't, it will "include()" an error.php file.

Is there anyway that I can write an htaccess rule that says, whenever this file is loaded, throw a 404? How else could I send that 404 inside of the error.php file, since it is not the first thing to be displayed?

Comment: .htaccess -> RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [R=404,L] in PHP file just @ob_flush();@header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

Comment: this worked find for when  http://url/error , but how do I make sure that whenever there is a redirect from http://url/example to http://url/error that the 404 is given again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this first on error.php, before outputting any error text.

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Comment: this won't work since there is some display before calling error.php

Comment: Not as far as I can tell - PHP searches MySQL, upon finding nothing includes error.php. Nothing has been output yet. Put this at the top of error.php and your error text underneath it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the header-function, just remember to do that before you output anything else.

I would recomend doing that instead of including another file, and then configure your server to serve an appropiate 404 file.

[PHP docs header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Be careful using w3schools (w3fools.com), I recommend always using the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php